# Find number of squares in a grid with restrictions (Optimise the runtime complexity)

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked this question in a recent interview. I tried to solve it post interview for the best time complexity but I am unable to come up with a proper approach. Here is the question. Any help in optimising the solution?

Given a grid (MxN) with some cells as reserved ('x') and some available (' '), find the number of squares that can be obtained from the grid.

Example: consider the grid

```
{
  {'x', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
  {' ', ' ', ' ', 'x'}
}
```

Here we can find 14 1x1 squares + 7 2x2 squares + 2 3x3 square = total 23 squares

I could create a brute force solution which I am adding below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char[][] grid = {{'x', ' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' ', 'x'}};
    int answer = getCount(grid);
    System.out.println(answer);
  }

  private static int getCount(char[][] grid) {
    int height = grid.length;
    int width = grid[0].length;
    int k = Math.min(height, width);
    int answer = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        //System.out.println("row = " + row + ", col = " + col);
        //System.out.println("answer = " + answer);
        if(grid[row][col] == ' ') {
          for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            if(isValidSubSquare(i, grid, row, col)) {
              answer++;
            }
          }
        }
        //System.out.println("answer = " + answer);
      }
    }
    return answer;
  }

  private static boolean isValidSubSquare(int i, char[][] grid, int row, int col) {
    if(row + i > grid.length || col + i > grid[0].length) return false;
    for(int r = 0; r < i; r++) {
      for(int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
        //System.out.println("row + r = " + (row + r) + ", col + c = " + (col + c));
        if(grid[row + r][col + c] == 'x') {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    //System.out.println("row = " + row + ", col = " + col + ", i = " + i);
    return true;
  }
}
```

I feel that the best runtime for this problem should be O(MN) with some Dynamic Programming involved. But I am unable to find any insight to further investigate.

Any kind of suggestion or correction will be very helpful.

Comment: The `isValidSubSquare` function was a bad idea, and needs to be removed. It takes O(k^2) all by itself, and the code calls it O(MNk) times.  After removing that function, you need to reorder the loops so that the `k` loop is first. That way, the row/col loops can always stay in bounds, e.g. `for (int row = 0; row <= height - k; row++)`. Then you get to the heart of the problem, which I will demonstrate by example. If you've found a 3x3 square at row=2 and col=2, then to check whether there's a 3x3 square at row=2 and col=3, all you need to do is check the last column of the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working java code based on גלעד ברקן idea:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final char[][] grid = { { 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }, { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' }, { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', ' ' } };
    final int answer = getCount(grid);
    System.out.println(answer);
  }

  private static int getCount(char[][] grid) {
    final var N = grid.length;
    final var M = grid[0].length;

    final var helper = new int[N][M];
    var sum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < M; y++) {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
          // top row and left column
          helper[x][y] = grid[x][y] == 'x' ? 0 : 1;
        } else {
          helper[x][y] =
              grid[x][y] == 'x' ? 0 : 1 + Math.min(helper[x - 1][y - 1], Math.min(helper[x][y - 1], helper[x - 1][y]));
        }
        sum += helper[x][y];
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For cell (i, j) as the southeast cell of a square, the largest square it can mark would be the smaller of (1) the free vector to the west, (2) the free vector to the north, and (3) the largest square with southeast cell at (i-1, j-1) + 1.

```
oooooooo
oooooooo
ooooxoox
oxoAAAAo
oooAAAAo
oooAAAAo
oooAAAAo
oooxoooB

largest_square(B) =
  min(4, 5, 5) =
  4x4
```

Comment: It works. It can be optimized a bit by calculating the min of (max squre (i-1,j-1), (i,j-1), (i-1, j) )+1

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- isValidSubsquare doesn't need to check values "< i-1" as they have been checked just before.
- if the subsquare is not valid, you can leave the "for i" loop
- you shouldn't need to check any field that's on a diagonal down from a checked field up to the maximum i you have found.